# running geoserver as background process in linux

Tags: geoserver, linux

I want to run geoserver as a background process:

```
sudo -b sh /usr/share/geoserver-2.8.3/bin/startup.sh
```

However, whenever I interact with the geoserver on the web surface, the process is suddenly re-appearing in the terminal an blocking further interaction. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Have you tried running it through [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Comment: try ./startup.sh &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Geoserver as a service in the background without any issues. There are [init scripts](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/linuxscript.html) for each linux distros to run it as a service.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running GeoServer from the command line then you are only testing it and so should leave it running in a spare console window until done.

In a production environment you need to use the .war file in a servlet container such as tomcat or jetty which will be run using service (or systemd or whatever your system uses) so that you don't need to worry about starting them.

Comment: Actually, I want to use geoserver standalone in production as well. Why is that wrong?

Comment: Because the bundled jetty is very old and it is unoptimized. Also you will need to log on and restart GeoServer each time. Finally you should not be running a service as root.